# Controller method can't be found when after copied project to Windows

Tags: grails

I'm working on Mac to develop a site. But I got the same project and same structure and copied it all to my Windows PC. After done all configuration I've tried to execute the project.

Everything work fine but one controller can't be found. This controller render a picture stored into a database and gives it to img html tag to render it back.

This controller and the method envolved executes as well on Mac even if I try to execute directly from URL, but in this other computer it can't be found and the output is an HTTP 404 error page.

Controller code:

```
class PhotoController {

    /**
     * Renderiza a foto em destaque de um evento
     */
    def renderMainImage() {
        if (params.id) {
            def photo = Photo.findByEventAndMain(Event.findById(params.id), true)

            if (photo?.resource) {
                response.setContentLength(photo.resource.length)
                response.outputStream.write(photo.resource)
            } else {
                //TODO renderizar com uma imagem padrão
                return null
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Tried cleaning your build? eg grails clean

Comment: I don't know why, but somehow the app works. I've tried clean and compile grails command exhaustively and close and open IDE about 3 times. But now still works!

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about how you can't "find" it? As in do you mean on the filesystem or in your IDE's explorer? Also please tell what IDE you are using.